# Data Factory MySQL Connectors

Tags: mysql, azure-data-factory, mysql-connector

Anyone got an idea of the difference between the **Azure Database for MySQL connector** and the **MySQL connector**.   I need to create a Linked Service to extract data from a VNet Peered MySQL database.  All help gratefully received.

FYI, when I test the Linked Service connection, I'm getting timeout.  SSL is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure MySQL connector is for MYSQL stored and managed by Microsoft as a service on Azure. The MYSQL connector is for MySQL on your on-prem environment or on a virtual machine in Azure.

If your MySQL server is in your own Vnet, and cannot be accessed from outside by data factory, you need to install a Self hosted integration runtime service inside your Vnet, to connect between MySQL and data factory.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious now you've stated it.  I need to stand up a VM on my side of the fence, put a SHIR in it, and use that to connect to the MySQL database in their VM.  Can't put the VM  next to the MySQL database, because they've got a Linux VM, and I need Windows to run a SHIR.  Thanks!